# PIR sensor is already high, even though it is not detecting any person

Tags: arduino-uno

I made codes like this through tinkercad.

```
const int temperature = A0;

int pir = 7;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(pir, INPUT);
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop()
{
  int pir_state = digitalRead(pir);
  
  int value_temp = analogRead(temperature);
  float volt = (value_temp * 5.0) / 1024.0;
  float tempC = (volt - 0.5)*100;
    
  if (tempC >= 22 && pir_state == 1)
  {
    Serial.print(tempC);
    Serial.println("C");
  }
  
  delay(1000);
}
```

And following picture is the picture of a circuit I made.

[image]

I simulated this circuit. Originally pir_state is gonna be zero when PIR sensor is not detecting any person or object, but pir_state is always high irrespective of detecting. I thought the value of pir went wrong, so I read pir out. Then, I found it out that pir's value is always 7 regardless of detecting.

I know this isn't a big deal to you guys, but actually I'm noob so I can't figure it out what's wrong. Please, could you help finding what's happening to this and tell me what is the problem?

Here, this is a link of the circuit I make.
https://www.tinkercad.com/things/luV81NLkWKo-engineering-designcapstone-design/editel?sharecode=qsYWcgpijodDbgIpsfluJ3yUJwuN-70doPT62QNTv1Q

Comment: The value of "pir" is 7 because that is the (pin) number that you assigned to it. You should be interested in the value of "pir_state", which should be the output of the PIR sensor. Your Tinkercad link requires an account, so most people would not bother to see what's there.

Comment: You can confirm the code by connecting pin 7 to ground insted of the PIR sensor. If pir_state is zero then the code works correctly. I don't know tinkercad in detail. How is the PIR sensor triggered while simulating? By clicking on it?

Comment: Not having (nor likely going to have) a TinkerCad account, I'm unable to sufficiently convince myself that the connection you've made to the output pin of the PIR sensor to the black lead terminating at digital pin 7 is valid according to the simulator. You could eliminate that concern by showing that you still have the problem when doing nothing different except using [a more conventional way of inserting it into the board](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/jkVCSRPQCFC-pir-sensor-with-led) which is also shown to work (without an account).

Comment: @user299980 I looked at your TinkerCAD model ... the PIR sensor is not connected to the arduino

Answer (score 0):

Update:

@jsotola commented that Tinkercad does have some capability simulate to the PIR's behavior. So my next step would be to temporarily replace the `if(){ ...` }' block in your loop() function with a few statements that print your inputs and calculated values once per second and run that while I tweaked the simulated PIR device and the thermo-sensor (if the simulation lets you do that).

The terminal output values should lead you to what ever isn't working the way you expected it to.

You are running your program in simulation, but the PIR sensor is an active device that responds to external physical inputs (changes in infrared illumination on it) modified by sensitivity settings on the device. It's hard to simulate a device's active environment. Unless the simulation offers you a way to simulate that, too, there really isn't a way to simulate the its inputs to your program, so a constant output (as seen by your simulated code) makes sense.

Without the simulator letting you pre-program the PIR's physical environment, the only way to see a its active behavior is to use a *real* PIR, and monitor it's real output while you change its actual environment - such as waving your hand in front of it - and watch response with an Arduino, an LED (and resistor) to ground, or a DVM.

Comment: TnkerCAD does show a PIR field of view when the simulation is running ... clicking a mouse pointer within the field generates a movement event

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that!